# Angular 2, Can't use Directive Attribute binding properly to display div box color/behavior

Tags: angular, components, angular2-directives

I'm a newbie learning Angular 2.

I'm trying to learn Directives with attribute binding to replicate a mouse enter/mouse leave events with simple box divs with colors on them. I'm following along a course on Udemy.

The @Input('highlight') should theoretically allow me to access the attribute binding in my template and bind it to a specific color there, if I'm not mistaken. Same goes for defaultColor. But it's not working.

**highlight.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[dirHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseover() {
    this.backgroundColor = this.highlightColor;
  };
  @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave() {
    this.backgroundColor = this.defaultColor;
  };
  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') get setColor() {
    return this.backgroundColor;
  };
  @Input() defaultColor = 'white';
  @Input('highlight') highlightColor = 'green';
  private backgroundColor: string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.backgroundColor = this.defaultColor;
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Attribute Directive</h1>
<h2>NgClass / NgStyle</h2>
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'red'}">
</div>
<hr />
<h2>Custom Attribute Directives</h2>
<div dirHighlight [highlight]="'blue'" [defaultColor]="'red'"]>Some Text</div>
```

**Error Messages in Chrome:**

```
Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ']' is not a valid attribute name.
    at DomRenderer.setElementAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:41681:31)
    at DebugDomRenderer.setElementAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:70770:24)
    at createRenderElement (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25732:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:143:17)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72058:21)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72510:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:16:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72071:21)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72527:52)
    at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:38612:25)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:36546:57)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:36365:89
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:36365:42)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:36317:27

zone.js:420 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:7:4 caused by: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ']' is not a valid attribute name. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:7:4 caused by: Failed to execute…, _nativeError: ZoneAwareError, originalError: DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ']' is not a valid attribute name.
    …, context: DebugContext, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent …t http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:36317:27"…} Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:7:4 caused by: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ']' is not a valid attribute name.

ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:7:…, rejection: ViewWrappedError, promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `]` is redundant just before `Some Text`.